# Rails through relationship timestamp

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a through relationship where the join table has a "created_at" column with timestamp. Is there anyway to access that? For example I'm accessing Artist.playlists in rails console but not getting timestamp.

Here are the models:

artists.rb

```
has_many :artist_playlists
has_many :playlists, through: :artist_playlists
```

playlist.rb

```
has_many :artist_playlists
has_many :artists, through: :artist_playlists
```

artist_playlist.rb

```
belongs_to :artist
belongs_to :playlist
```

Comment: Is there a `t.timestamps` in your migration?

Comment: You question is not clarified enough ! Do you need to access the timestamps related to playlists ?
you'd better to access the playlists through artist_playlist so that your relation make sense ! some thing like this : 

playlist_ids = Artist.artist_playlists.pluck(:playlist_id)

then :
@sometimestamps = Playlist.where(id: playlist_ids).pluck(:created_at)

Comment: @Oscar Sidebo  you need to have timestamps specified in the join table migration then only you will get access to them by using `Artist.artist_playlists.pluck(:created_at)` gives you timestamps array

Answer (score 0):

```
playlists = Artist.playlists
```

will return

```
<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy [playlist_1, playslist_2,...]
```

So to get created_at of individual playlist

```
 playlists.each do |playlist|
  puts playlist.created_at
 end
```

Or to get all created_at as array

```
playlists_cretaed_at = Artist.playlists.pluck(:created_at)
```

Comment: Should clarify that the timestamp column exist on the artist_playlist table not the playlist table. The artist_playlist table has several rows with same artist_id & playlist_id combination so I need to be able to sort by when they were created_at.

Answer (score 0):

You can put your sort/order filter on created_at while fetching records i.e

Artist.first.playlists.order('artist_playlists.created_at desc')

Comment: @OscarSidebo can you please upvote. So I able to continue answer. please.